# I am using localeCompare for sorting in antd but getting error don't know why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using localeCompare for sorting in antd table but getting error don't know why, It's working fine  in another table. What should I to do ?

The Error Is : **"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'localeCompare')"**

village is coming from database
hare is data

*address: "prabhani"
affiliateId: 178
affiliateScreenState: "DRIVING_LICENSE_SCREEN"
dateOfBirth: "28/04/2004"
district: "Pune"
firstName: "vipin"
gender: "MALE"
lastName: "mishra"
middleName: ""
phoneNumber: "9930486852"
state: "Maharashtra"
status: "PENDING_DEPOSIT"
village: "Shivajinagar"*

```
 {
      title: 'Village',
      dataIndex: 'village',
      key: 'village',
      sorter: (a, b) => a.village.localeCompare(b.village),
    },
    {
      title: 'District',
      dataIndex: 'district',
      sorter: (a, b) => a.district.localeCompare(b.district),
      key: 'district',
    },
```

```
 <Table
          dataSource={affiliates}
          columns={affiliatesData}
          className="stateCustomTable"
          rowKey={(record) => record.affiliateId}
           loading={{indicator: <div><Grid
          height="100"
          width="100"
          color='#ef790d'
          ariaLabel='loading'
        /></div>, spinning: loading }}
          showSorterTooltip={false}
        />
```

I don't know what can be the issue.

**Thanks**

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'localeCompare')

Comment: Then `a.village` or `a.district` is `undefined`. Impossible to say which or why with the information provided here.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry Sir Now I Think Provided full information

Comment: But where is `sorter` called? How are you retrieving and parsing this data? You have yet to produce a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please check if each record have the following fields or not. It will throw error when it can't find any key. Use `optional chaining operator`. 
sorter: (a, b) => a?.village?.localeCompare(b?.village),
Modify all the sorter function. It should work now.

Comment: in antd when we add "sorter" and click in column header its will call automatic